# How to do this with Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table structure like this

```
id  status action amount fid
1    P      Yes   3000    10
2    P      No    2000    10
3    P      Yes   6000    10
4    D      Yes   500     10
5    D      No    600     10
6    V      Yes   800     10
```

i want to filter with --> status P action Yes, status D action No, and status V action Yes one time. The result will be based on fid.

output like that ---->

```
amount(name1) amount(name2) amount(name3)
9000            600          800
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only intend to report on the three statuses shown in the sample data above, we can try:

```
SELECT
    fid,
    SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE status = 'P' AND action = 'Yes') AS amount_1,
    SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE status = 'D' AND action = 'No')  AS amount_2,
    SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE status = 'V' AND action = 'Yes') AS amount_3
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY fid;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

Comment: Thank you @Tim Biegeleisen. I got the desired output.